# Tratamento de DataGridView

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview

Tenho que apresentar uma lista de objeto em um DataGridView estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
class EntradaModel
{

    int codigo, motivo, anterior, quantidade;
    string observacao, tipo;
    DepositoModel deposito = new DepositoModel();
    ProdutoModel produto = new ProdutoModel();

    public int Codigo
    {
        get { return codigo; }
        set { codigo = value; }
    }

    public ProdutoModel Produto
    {
        get { return produto; }
        set { produto = value; }
    }

    public DepositoModel Deposito
    {
        get { return deposito; }
        set { deposito = value; }
    }
}
```

Form:

```
public partial class EntradaEstoque : Form
{
   List<EntradaModel> listEntrada;
   EntradaModel objEntrada;

    public EntradaEstoque()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listEntrada = new List<EntradaModel>();
        objEntrada = new EntradaModel();
    }


    private void btnAddAnimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (verificaCampos())
        {
            objEntrada = null;
            objEntrada = new EntradaModel();
            objEntrada.Produto.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigoProduto.Text);
            objEntrada.Deposito.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cboDeposito.SelectedValue);
            objEntrada.Motivo = Convert.ToInt32(cboMotivo.SelectedValue);
            objEntrada.Quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantidade.Text);
            objEntrada.Observacao = txtObservacao.Text;
            listEntrada.Add(objEntrada);
            cboDeposito.Enabled = false;

            carregarGrid();

            limparCampos();
        }
    }

    public void carregarGrid()
    {
        Functions.configuracoesGrade(dgvProduto);
        dgvProduto.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvProduto.DataSource = null;
        dgvProduto.DataSource = listEntrada;
    }
```

Porem, a DataGridView fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisava que na coluna produto fosse apresentado o Nome do produto. 
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Ele está exibindo o nome dos objetos.. DEPOSITO e PRODUTO... você tem que criar propriedades para esses campos e não criar as colunas automaticamente... Tem como colocar seu HTML aqui?

Comment: Tem esse artigo aqui de como fazer isso. http://www.devcurry.com/2010/11/bind-aspnet-gridview-to-custom-object.html

Comment: Estou fazendo windows form e não web.

Comment: vc tem uma classe de nome `Functions` com método `configuracoesGrade` o que ela faz com gridview? Outra coisa vc sempre atribui `null` antes de usar o Controle, prq isso?  Em nenhuma parte do seu Evento `btnAddAnimal`, vc atribuiu o nome do produto a uma propriedade. Em vez de `objEntrada.Deposito.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cboDeposito.SelectedValue);` use o `SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá

2 Pontos a serem feitos.

1 - Na sua classe adicione 2 propriedades, que são.

Assumindo que o Código do Produto é um INT

```
public int CodigoProduto
    {
        get { return this.Produto.Codigo; }
    }

//Assumindo que NomeDeposito é a propriedade dentro de Deposito
public String NomeDeposito
    {
        get { return this.Deposito.NomeDeposito; }
    }
```

No seu GridView faça deste modo

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvProduto"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CodigoProduto" HeaderText="Produto" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="NomeDeposito" HeaderText="Depósito" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Eu só mostrei como fazer os 2 que você não estava conseguindo, adicione os outros campos usando o mesmo modo.

EDIT ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Como você falou que está usando WINDOWS FORM.

Um modo que você pode fazer, é criar um objeto com os campos *NomeProduto* e *NomeDepoisto*. Segue

```
public class NovoObjeto {
   int codigo, motivo, anterior, quantidade;
    string observacao, tipo, deposito,produto;

    public int Codigo
    {
        get { return codigo; }
        set { codigo = value; }
    }

    public Int CodigoProduto
    {
        get { return produto; }
        set { produto = value; }
    }

    public String NomeDeposito
    {
        get { return deposito; }
        set { deposito = value; }
    }
}


public void carregarGrid()
{
    Functions.configuracoesGrade(dgvProduto);
    dgvProduto.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dgvProduto.DataSource = null;

    List<NovoObjeto> novaLista = new List<NovoObjeto>
    foreach(EntradaModel e in listaEntrada){


     novaLista.add(new NovoObjeto(){ PARAMETROS = e.Parametros });
    }

    dgvProduto.DataSource = novaLista;
}
```

Tem um modo de fazer isso com o auto wizzard do .net, mas aí é mais complicado de explicar aqui.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: Estou fazendo uma aplicação windows form.